# Is there a C++ function which enables to divide vector into three seperate vectors?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector

I am looking for a solution to divide vector into 3 separate vectors with proportion of elements 9:1:1, for example if we had 1100 elements in original vector then I expect to get 3 vectors with consecutively 900, 100 and 100 elements. There is a function std::partition_copy, however it copies data only to 2 separate vectors.

Comment: There is nothing built in for this.  You'll need to create your own function.

Comment: there is a constructor taking two iterators to a range of elements. You just need to call it 3 times. Note that `std::partition_copy` copies elements, ie the target elements must exist already (unless you use a back inserter)

Comment: @Jakub Fraszczak Just write a proposal to the C++ Standard Committee to include such a function.:)

Comment: That sounds a lot like a X-Y problem. From the number and size of the split, I'll guess you are splitting machine learning data into test, train, validate ? Then just keep your original vector, and pass along iterators that points into it to the function using it.

Comment: The real "historic" problem here is that std::vectors are everything but actual vectors. They're kind of containers, but they lack fundamental features of mathematical vectors — primary one being "addition" — while providing some that are unwanted with vectors (deleting a term, shifting next ones to the left). They never should have been named that way in the beginning IMHO.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard algorithm to do what you want directly. I suppose there are too many special cases to be considered. For example, how to distribute elements according to 9:1:1 when the initial vector has only eg 9 elements? Should each partition contain at least 1 element? Should the result be 7:1:1 or 8:1:0?

However, you can use `std::vector`s constructor taking two iterators:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    
    std::vector<int> v(10);
    std::iota(v.begin(),v.end(),0);

    size_t mid1 = v.size()*0.8;
    size_t mid2 = mid1+v.size()*0.1;

    std::vector<int> v1{v.begin(),v.begin()+mid1};
    std::vector<int> v2{v.begin()+v1.size(),v.begin()+mid2};
    std::vector<int> v3{v.begin()+v1.size()+v2.size(),v.end()};

    for (const auto& e : v1) std::cout << e << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (const auto& e : v2) std::cout << e << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
    for (const auto& e : v3) std::cout << e << " ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

When the number of items is given in absolute numbers the above issues cannot arise and you could write a generic algorithm that fills `n` vectors with `m_i` (`0<=i<n`) elements from a source vector.

Last but not least, consider that copying a whole vector, just to be able to access subranges of it, is not very idiomatic. Instead of creating new vectors that contain parts of the elements you should refactor the methods working on those subranges to take iterators instead of vectors, ie

```
 template <typename Iterator>
 void do_something_with_vector_elements(Iterator begin,Iterator end);
```

instead of

```
 void do_something_with_all_vector_elements(const std::vector<int>& v);
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the ranges denoted by those iterators (without copying all the data). And you vindicate the design decision of `<algorithm>` to take iterator pairs instead of containers as parameters

Comment: @Caleth my general advice is "just don't do it". Often it comes across as rather annyoing, but yes, its probably appropriate here. Will add a note

Answer (score 0):

There is not a standard function for this. What would the function return? A vector of yet more vectors? That's fine for a at-home solution to a problem, but I feel like the standards committee would not be happy with a function that did that. Or if it were to take iterators to the destination vectors, how many destination vectors? These things would be defined. And I don't think the committee would be happy with making N new algorithms for each number of output vectors as well.

You could roll your own function however, making extensive use of partial vector copying:

```
std::vector<int> newVec(oldVec.begin(), oldVec.begin() + 8);
// copies the first 8 elements of oldVec into newVec
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!